# Is it possible to use switch case to go through a table's rows and act on one element

Tags: jquery

I want to create an add button which  when clicked adds the current value of a selectbox to a textarea. I want to act upon the button's name, so for example whenever a button with the name "add" is clicked i want the value of the first  element of that  to be written to  the text area.

So far i have something like this, but even the alert won't trigger and i don't know what i'm missing.

http://jsfiddle.net/CZNwX/6/

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I think I didn't express what i wanted clearly:

So for example: when i click the add button to the right of the first selectbox , the value of that selectbox(and only that one) will get written to the textarea, or as the case is an alert with the value of the selectbox will appear.

Also edited the jsfiddle code

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement will return a jQuery object but your case statements are looking to match string values -

```
        switch( $("#t1 tbody tr")){
            case "property_id_line":
```

you could alter your switch statement to -

```
            switch( $("#t1 tbody tr").eq(1).attr("id")){
                case "property_id_line":
```

which will return the id of the second row (the first row of your table contains your drop down) rather than a jQuery object representing all the rows in your table.

Also I think you may need to loop through the rows in your table using `each`, your current code is returning a reference to all the rows in your table.

Also, in your fiddle your button selector isn't quite right so the click event isn't firing, the code below will display the first of your alerts -

```
$('input[type="button"][name="add"]').bind('click',function(){ 
            switch( $("#t1 tbody tr").eq(1).attr("id")){
                case "property_id_line":
                    alert("asdasda");
                    break;
                case "property_periodsInUse_line":
                    alert($("#t1").find("select option:selected").eq(1).text());
                    break;
            }  
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/tFCgG/1/

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried that but still not even the alert showing.

Comment: I edited the main post and also the jsfiddle code with what i'm trying at the moment. though still i would like to act on the button's name

Answer (score 1):

replace `$("#t1 tbody tr")` for `$("#t1 tbody tr").prop("id")`

Answer (score 0):

Your initial selector won't get anything `$('button[name="add"]')`, there are no `<button>` elements in your HTML. There are `input[type=button]` elements though...

Comment: yea sorry bout that, in the original app i have a link styled as a button when i replaced it with button i missed the "input".